# Windows Small Business Server CAL Question

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-sbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We are in the process of upgrading to a new server, to be specific it's the following setup:

HP Proliant ML110 G6 Tower Server
Windows Server Small Business Edition 5 Cal License

We have around 30 staff, but we only want 4 levels of access. For example, an office user level, a completely locked out level for work experience users and a directors level.

If we got the 5 user license for the Windows Server, could multiple people login as the same user at the same time? Or, is the only way to do it to get licenses for each and every employee?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can license per user - in which case 30 CALs needed for each staff member.  If users are sharing machines (e.g. work part time) you could go for the per device CAL instead which may work out cheaper for you but it sounds like you need to be going the per user route

Answer (score 0):

You will require a license for each user or each computer that connects. [SBS info](http://www.microsoft.com/sbs/en/us/licensing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to purchase a further 25 User OR Device CALs. I believe you can get a 20-pack and a further 5-pack CALs at some discount level.

You haven't mentioned which edition you have got but you must purchase the correct license for that particular edition to be compliant.